# How to convert date time in varchar to date in oracle to get one month data

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have data in `oracle` table where date field `Created_Date` is in format `01/01/2022 7:00:00 PM` which is of type `varchar2` ,i want to get  past one month data, and i did below query which is not working

```
select *from Mn_Fdd_tbl where to_date(to_char(Created_Date,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) > trunc(sysdate)-30;
```

Comment: . . . and may we point out that storing a date in a VARCHAR2 column is, in and of itself, a serious design flaw.  Oracle implements data types DATE and TIMESTAMP, and those should be used.  Also note that DATE actually includes time, down to the second.  Also note that it is all stored in an internal binary format, and is made readable to a human through the use of the TO_CHAR function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
select * 
from mn_fdd_tbl
where to_date(created_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1);
```

because

- no point in `TO_CHAR`-ing something that's already a string ...

  - ... with a wrong format model
- "last month": not all months have 30 days, so - your "calculation" is wrong for approx. 50% of months. Use `add_months` instead

Comment: will it contain AM also along with PM?

Comment: Yes; it'll work for both AM and PM.